# How can I write in Landau notation (or the like) that $2^x/x$ rises almost as fast as $2^x$?

Tags: notation, asymptotics, exponential-function

Since $2^x \not\in O(2^x/x)$, we do not have $O(2^x/x)=O(2^x)$.

But since $x$ rises linearly and $2^x$ exponentially, $2^x/x$ rises almost as fast as $2^x$. Can I somehow express this in Landau notation or the like?

---

Details: I guess I could just say that both rise exponentially, but since $2^x/x = (2/\sqrt[x]{x})^x$ is asymptotically closer to $2^x$ than $c^x$ is (for a constant $c \neq 2$), I am looking for a notation/solution that is finer grained.

Comment: Have you considered $(2-o(1))^x$? (the $-$ sign isn't important but might help readability).

Comment: Thanks Erick, that does summarize my argument/thoughts. Do you think $O((2-o(1))^x)$ is more readable than $O(2^x/x)$? For me, it's borderline, and gets even borderlinier since I need it in a more complex expression like $O(v^x * w * y * z * 1/x)$, which I want to simplify.

Comment: How about taking the logarithm and writing $\log(2^x/x) = O(\log 2^x)$?

Comment: @Fabian Hmm that doesn't distinguish between $c^x$ and $2^x$, does it?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Fabian. I thought about some logarithmic solution too, but did not find any :( I believe $log 2^x \not\in O(log(2^x / x))$, so the problem remains the same - as Erick already commented.

Comment: @DaveBallakauser750378: why $\log 2^x= x \log2$ is not in $O(\log(2^x/x)) = O(x \log 2 + \log x)$?

Comment: @ErickWong: no it doesn't.

Comment: @DaveBallakauser750378 Fabian is correct $\log 2^x = O(\log 2^x/x))$; the problem isn't lack of correctness but lack of specificity.

Comment: @DaveBallakauser750378 Hmmm if it were $\Theta(2^x/x)$ then at least we could drop the $\Theta$ as it can be subsumed into $(2-o(1))^x$.

Comment: @Fabian: thanks a lot for your correction. Is $2^x \not\in O(2^x/x)$ correct? So by taking the logarithm, only the exponential characteristic remains and the "nuance $1/x$ is filtered". Correct?

Comment: @Erick: In my situation, I do not have $\Theta(\dots)$ anyways.

Comment: @DaveBallakauser750378 If you are happy to overlook arbitrary factors of polynomial size, you could consider appropriating an "approximate-$O$" notation like $\tilde{O}$, which is sometimes used to ignore factors of size $\log x$, after defining it explicitly.

Comment: @Erick: awesome, just what I was looking for. If you turn your comment into an answer with a citeable reference where $\tilde{O}$ is used, I'll accept your answer immediately.

Comment: A more universally understandable notation is that $$2^x/x=2^{\Theta(x)},$$ or, less precise but probably sufficient, $$2^x/x=2^{O(x)}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Big_O_notation&section=22#Extensions_to_the_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations]) entry, the "soft-O" notation is common in computer science, with $f(n) \in \tilde{O}(g(n))$ being shorthand for $f(n) \in O(g(n) \log^k g(n))$ for some constant $k$.  In particular, $\tilde{O}(2^x/x) = \tilde{O}(2^x)$.

von zur Gathen and Gerhard attribute this notation to a 1988 paper of Babai, Luks, and Seress, but I don't know the exact reference.  It could well be this one:

SIAM Journal on Computing, 1997, Vol. 26, No. 5 : pp. 1310-1342

Fast Management of Permutation Groups I
László Babai, Eugene M. Luks, and Ákos Seress

I found http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~luks/fast.pdf which uses $O^\sim\!(g(n))$ rather than $\tilde{O}(g(n))$.